# calculate cosine similarity faster

Tags: java, search-engine, k-means, cosine-similarity

I wanna use cosine similarity in my IR project but because the size of vectors are big and it must multiply floats many times, it takes a long time.

is there any way to calculate cosine similarity faster?

here is my code:

```
private double diffrence(HashMap<Integer, Float> hashMap,
 HashMap<Integer, Float> hashMap2 ) {
    Integer[] keys = new Integer[hashMap.size()];
    hashMap.keySet().toArray(keys);

     float ans = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (hashMap2.containsKey(keys[i])) {
             ans += hashMap.get(keys[i]) * hashMap2.get(keys[i]);

        }
    }

     float hashLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
         hashLength += (hashMap.get(keys[i]) * hashMap.get(keys[i]));
    }
     hashLength = (float) Math.sqrt(hashLength);

    Integer[] keys2 = new Integer[hashMap2.size()];
    hashMap2.keySet().toArray(keys2);

     float hash2Length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < keys2.length; i++) {

         hash2Length += hashMap2.get(keys2[i]) * hashMap2.get(keys2[i]);

    }
     hash2Length = (float) Math.sqrt(hash2Length);

    return (float) (ans /(hash2Length*hashLength));
}
```

Comment: Faster than what? You should really show some code, or at least describe your algorithm. If you're not using a sparse vector representation, you're doing it suboptimally.

Comment: You have got all your cores running red-hot haven't you ?

Comment: @Ulterior : what do you mean?

Comment: @larsmans : I added my code.

Comment: Have you profiled this code? Do you know what part of it takes time? With so much hash table lookup going on, I wouldn't be too worried about a few floating-point ops. (E.g. `hashMap.get(keys[i]) * hashMap.get(keys[i])` looks up the exact same key twice, while you could have cached the result.)

Comment: isn't it O(1)? any difference?

Comment: @Paniz: it's not about O(1), it's about actual performance. Hash tables are really slow vector representations. And besides, if you're doing *n* lookups followed by *n* multiplications, then both take O(*n*) time in total.

Answer (score 9):

Typically in IR, one vector has far fewer non-zero elements than the other (and usually the query vector is the sparser one, but this is true even for document vectors). You can save time by looping over the keys of the *sparser* vector, i.e. the smaller hash map, looking them up in the larger one.

As for pkacprzak's suggestion of a lookup table and your lack of memory: realize that normalization can be done prior to the cosine similarity computations. For each vector, before storing it, compute its norm and divide every element by that. Then, you can just compute a dot product and get a cosine similarity out.

I.e., cosine similarity is usually defined as

```
x·y / (||x|| × ||y||)
```

but that's equal to

```
(x / ||x||) · (y / ||y||)
```

where `/` is element-wise division. If you each replace `x` by `x / ||x||`, then you only need to compute `x·y`.

If you combine these two bits of advice, you get a cosine similarity algorithm that takes just one loop over the smaller of the two inputs.

Further improvements can be made by using smarter [sparse vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) structures; hash tables have a *lot* of overhead both in lookup and iteration.

Comment: as I use the values on the other methods I can not replace as u said.
the hashmap doesn't have any zero value, and because I wanna look up in the hashmap for the other hashmap's key I think it is the best DS. isn't it?

Comment: @Paniz: the elements that are not present in a hash table are implicitly zero, aren't they? And no, hash tables are *not* the ideal data structure for sparse vectors, as I keep explaining. A sorted list of (index,value) pairs can make things much faster. If you want to stick to hash tables, you're never going to get really good performance out of this.

Comment: if i change it to the list of(index,value)  and then sort it would the sort time would be less than this code?

Comment: @Paniz: sorting can be done offline, so the cost is distributed over many cosine similarity computations.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are too many vectors to precompute the cosine similarity of each pair, but you could precompute the length of every vector and store it using a lookup table. This reduces a constant factor in computing the cosine similarity of two vectors - actually it saves a significant amount of time, because of a lot of floating point operations.

I'm assuming that you are not wasting memory by storing zeros in the vector.

Comment: because I have limitation in memory I can't save any thing more :(

Comment: @Paniz if you have n vectors, then storing precomputed lengths consumes only n additional floats. Futhermore, to save memory you could replace a HashMap with a simpler data structure like a list.

Comment: total numbers are about 42000 and because the center changes on each iteration storing the size of the center wouldn't be useful.
do you still say it would be better to save them?
is it hashmap or floats multiplication that is time consuming?

Comment: @Paniz what do you mean by a center?

Comment: I use it in k-means clustering each cluster have a center and the center updates on each iteration.

Comment: @Paniz So why don't you not precompute a length of every point (as a possible center) at the beginning of the algorithm?

Comment: because the centers are not points.they are the mean of points and may not be one of the points.

Comment: the program knows the number of all possible values for `key`, so you can dimension the vectors for the centers (which I assume are many fewer than the number of vectors) to this number. Assuming your possible values for `key` are consecutive and start at zer0 (if not, you could apply a mapping as part of the initial preprocessing) you can even use the `key` in the loop over the other vector as index into the means vector.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to pre-normalizing your vectors as others suggested already and assuming your list of vectors is not changing, transform them to pairs of arrays **once** (outside the similarity function) and sort them by the key index, e.g.:

```
Integer[] keys = new Integer[hashMap.size()];
Float values[] = new Float[keys.size()];
int i = 0;
float norm = ...;    
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Float> entry : new TreeMap<Integer, Float>(hashMap).entrySet())
{
   keys[i] = entry.getKey();
   values[i++] = entry.getValue() / norm;
}
```

then to do the actual similarity calculation (assuming you then pass `keys1`, `values`, `keys2`, `values2` instead of two `HashMaps`), your innermost loop reduces to:

```
float ans = 0;
int i,j = 0;
while (i < keys1.length && j < keys2.length)
{
  if (keys1[i] < keys2[j])
    ++i;
  else if (keys1[i] > keys2[j])
    ++j;
  else
    // we have the same key in 1 and 2
    ans += values1[i] * values2[j];
}
```

You could even consider to store all `keys` and `values` of all vectors consecutively in a large array of `int` and `float`, keeping another array with indices into the first positions:

```
int sumOfAllVectorLengths = ...;
int allKeys[] = new int[sumOfAllVectorLengths];
float allValues[] = new float[sumOfAllVectorLengths];
int firstPos = new int[numberOfVectors + 1]; 
firstPos[numberOfVectors] = sumOfAllVectorLengths;

int nextFirstPos = 0;
int index = 0;

for (HashMap<Integer, Float> vector : allVectors)
{
   firstPos[index] = nextFirstPos;

   float norm = ...;    
   for (Map.Entry<Integer, Float> entry : new TreeMap<Integer, Float>(hashMap).entrySet())
   {
      keys[nextFirstPos] = entry.getKey();
      values[nextFirstPos++] = entry.getValue() / norm;
   }

   ++index; 
}
```

and then just pass the arrays and the indices of the vectors to the comparison function.

Comment: I need to look up in the hashmap as fast as possible

Comment: the overall time required actually depends on how many vectors `n` you have and how many (`k`) similarity calculations you do. If `k` is much smaller than `n` (few similarity calculations, many vectors), the above may not gain you much. If on the other hand, `k` is much larger than `n` (e.g. you want to calculate the similarity for all possible pairs, i.e. `k = n^2`), precomputing certain quantities (assuming it's `O(n)`) in order to save time in the `k` similarity calculations will most likely speed things up.

What I'm proposing is that you convert the hashmaps into linear arrays beforehand.

Comment: my work is the firs case you told.
is the time because of float computation or work with hashmap?

Comment: I only saw now that you want to do k-means clustering, so you will compare each of the `n` vectors to each of the `k` centers (`k` here is different from my previous comment) several times (so you will do x times `n * k` comparisons).

Comment: my main question is that it takes time because of the float computations or because of using hashmap?
(what you said about comparisons is completely right)

Comment: if you want to know where your program spends most of its time, as @larsmans already suggested, use a Java profiler (I think netbeans and eclipse have one integrated etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the project simbase https://github.com/guokr/simbase , it is a vector similarity nosql database.

Simbase use below concepts:

- Vector set: a set of vectors
- Basis: the basis for vectors, vectors in one vector set have same basis
- Recommendation: a one-direction binary relationship between two vector sets which have the same basis

The write operation is handled in a single thread per basis, and comparison between any two vectors is needed, so the write operation is scaled at O(n).

We had a non-final performance test for the dense vectors on an i7-cpu Macbook, it can easily handle 100k 1k-dimensional vectors with each write operation in under 0.14 sec; and if the linear scale ratio can hold, it means Simbase can handle 700k dense vectors with each write operation in under 1 sec.

Answer (score -2):

I can clearly see at least one place, where you are simply wasting CPU cycles:

```
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (hashMap2.containsKey(keys[i])) {
         ans += hashMap.get(keys[i]) * hashMap2.get(keys[i]);
    }
}

float hashLength = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
     hashLength += (hashMap.get(keys[i]) * hashMap.get(keys[i]));
}
```

here you have 2 cycles of the same bounds on the same 2 hashMaps. Why won't you just do it in one cycle:

```
float hashLength = 0;
int hm = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    hm = hashMap.get(keys[i])*hashMap2.get(keys[i]);
    hashLength += hm;
    if (hashMap2.containsKey(keys[i])) {
         ans += hm;
    }
}
```

By the way, is there any special reason of using hashMap? Or you can do with some simpler sort of array?

Comment: Computing cosine similarity does not actually involve the `cos` function. It's the normalized dot product of two vectors -- the name stems from the fact that such a dot product is equal to the cosine of the angle between the vectors.

Comment: @larsmans If something equals cosine of an angle between two vectors, then how are you supposed to find it without calculating cosine of that angle? In any case, precalculated tables will let him get rid of floating point operations.

Comment: For vectors x and y, x·y/(||x||×||y||) = cos(θ) where θ is the angle between x and y. That's just addition, multiplication and reciprocal. See [Introduction to IR](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/dot-products-1.html) for details.

Comment: ... and `sqrt`. Sorry, I forgot that one.

Comment: i need hashmap to store the index of the word and their weight, I need to look up the in the constant time

Comment: @Paniz And are you able to call external .so libraries, written in plain C for such heavy computational fragments? If you do, you may calculate those vectors in much faster fashion.

Comment: What I'm saying is you to take this part of calculations out, into compiled C program. Can you handle this?